# Github Actions - multiple cache with same key

Tags: caching, github-actions

I'm trying to maintain separate caches for each build environment (qa, staging, prod). So that whenever I try to build for the QA environment, a particular cache is used to speed up the build process. I'm triggering this build workflow by creating a release.

My problem is while retrieving the cache in the cache step, the cache is always missed and it creates a new cache every time with the same key. My cache key is `${{ runner.os }}-buildx-${{ env.deploy_env }}`. When I look at GitHub cache page. I see multiple caches with the same key.

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and the accepted solution is not my case, I have multiple caches with the same key in the same branch. Was it your case? or did you find something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflows [can only restore caches from a base branch, the current branch or the default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#restrictions-for-accessing-a-cache). It's hard do tell from the screenshot, but if those caches are from different tags, that is why there is more than one cache.